# how to Get only the rows which's D column hold nearest lowest number to the C column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
------------------------------------------
  ID       Name      C     D 
------------------------------------------
  1      AK-47      10    5
  2        RPG      10    20 
  3        Mp5      20    15
  4     Sniper      20    18 
  5       Tank      90    80
  6    Space12      90    20
  7      Rifle      90    110
  8      Knife      90    85
```

Consider `1,2 ; 3,4 ; 5,6,7,8` are as separate groups 
So i need to get the row group wise that which's D column holds the nearest lower number to the C column

**So the Expected Result is :**

```
    ------------------------------------------
  ID       Name      C     D 
------------------------------------------
  1      AK-47      10    5
  4     Sniper      20    18 
  8      Knife      90    85
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the syntax for another way of doing this. This uses a cte and will only hit the base table once.

```
with MySortedData as
(
    select ID, Name, C, D, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY C order by ABS(C - D)) as RowNum
    from Something
)

select *
from MySortedData
where RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
  select c, min(abs(c-d)) as near
  from your_table
  group by c
) t2 on t1.c = t2.c and abs(t1.c-t1.d) = t2.near
```

Comment: Is this return row with nearest lowest number ? , I need the nearest lower number, does this querry do the trick ?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: I was doubting because of min(abs(c-d)) function. Ok I will try it and let you know.

Comment: You could do this using ROW_NUMBER also which would perform better on large datasets because you only hit the table once.